# App stopped unexpectedly when exited

Tags: android, forceclose

My application stopped unexpectedly when I pressed the back button and needed to be forced closed. Here's the error log:

```
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at com.example.musicshare.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity$1.run(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:337)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
11-16 14:57:34.595: E/AndroidRuntime(4899):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your log:

```
11-12 14:21:20.080: E/AndroidRuntime(8843): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.musicshare/com.example.musicshare.ZoneActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

You have not declared ZoneActivity on your Android Manifest.. open your Android Manifest and add:

```
<activity android:name=".ZoneActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the information that is interesting for you:

`Unable to find explicit activity class com.example.musicshare/com.example.musicshare.ZoneActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

It seems like the Activity that is defined within your manifest does not exist in your code.

Comment: Hm, that means you fixed something wrong/the required class is not part of your package or the exception you get is now regarding something different.